# accssing blob storage by php

Tags: php, azure-storage

I am not a php developer and it is my first time working with php. I am assigned to a project to move it to Windows Azure. the application is php ( I think it is old php because there is no classes or objects). I am going to use Blob storage to save uploaded files. I have read a a lot of articles regarding php and WA. 
PHP has been installed by using a web role and Platform installer. the application works and communicate with sql azure. but when I follow this article

```
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlining/archive/2012/07/18/new-connection-pattern-in-the-php-client-libraries-for-windows-azure.aspx
```

it renders 500 error. I am mistaking maybe old php is not compatible with object oriented php.
thanks for your advice.

Comment: What is the error message in your log?

Comment: In EventViewer there was no errors however in c:\windows\temp\php53_errors.log first I found "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder' not found in E:\approot\index.php on line 186".
I have already added "use windowsazure\common\servicebuilder" so I added 
require_once 'WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder.php';
Now it generates: 
"PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\StorageServiceSettings' not found in E:\approot\WindowsAzure\Common\ServicesBuilder.php on line 208".

Comment: after a while it says now:

PHP Warning:  require_once(HTTP/Request2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in E:\approot\WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php on line 33
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'HTTP/Request2.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in E:\approot\WindowsAzure\Common\Internal\Http\HttpClient.php on line 33

Comment: this problem is now solved by adding pear folder to approot and modifing include_path to inlcude pear folder.